# YII Subdirectories in Models

Tags: php, yii

I have a subdirectory in "Models" called "Countries", inside of it there's 
for instance USA.php, now when I try to do `$country = new USA();` I get

> include(USA.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Although when the USA.php file is directly under Models/ it works just fine.

Comment: Have you tried adding `path.to.models.Countries.*` to your `config/main.php` import array?

Comment: yes I did, but it doesn't work, should I write something other than "new USA();" ?

Comment: Ok it worked, I added the wrong combination that's all, is there a way to do it recursively ?

Comment: No, you cannot import them recursively. See: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12103-how-to-import-all-files-under-a-specific-folder-and-its-sub-folders/

Comment: The best way is to use Namespaces http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace